# In proving $\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ don't we need restrictions on values of $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions

> 9. The functions $\sinh$ and $\tanh$ are one-one; their inverses $\sinh^{-1}$ and $\tanh^{-1}$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and $(-1,1)$, respectively. These inverse functions are sometimes denoted by $\arg\sinh$ and $\arg\tanh$ (the "argument" of the hyperbolic sine and tangent.
>    If $\cosh$ is restricted to $[0,\infty)$ it has an inverse, denoted by
>    $\arg\cosh$, or simply $\cosh^{-1}$, which is defined on $[1,\infty)$.
>
> Prove, using information from problem $8$, that
>
> (b) $\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{1+x^2}\tag{1}$

Shouldn't there be a restriction on the values that $x$ can take in $(1)$ (such restrictions are present in other items in this problem, for example)?

In problem $8$ we proved that

$$\cosh^2-\sinh^2=1\tag{1}$$

Hence, expression $(1)$ evaluated at a point $\sinh^{-1}(x)$ is

$$\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))-\sinh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=1$$

$$\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))-x^2=1$$

$$\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=1+x^2\tag{2}$$

$$\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{1+x^2}\tag{3}$$

Consider the step from $(2)$ to $(3)$.

In $(2)$ don't we need to restrict $\sinh^{-1}(x)$ to be in $[1,\infty)$?

Ie

$$\sinh^{-1}(x)\in [1,\infty)$$

Now, since $\sinh$ is increasing and

$$\sinh^{-1}(x)=1 \implies x=\sinh{1}$$

then if $x\in[\sinh{1},\infty)$ then $\sinh^{-1}(x) \in [1,\infty)$.

Finally, just to confirm, the reason we take the positive square root is because $\cosh$ always positive, correct?

Comment: Your $\sin\,$s should be $\sinh\,$s.

Comment: In the real variable we don't, because $\sinh:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is bijective and $\cosh:\Bbb R\to [1,\infty)$ is non-negative.

Comment: The reason why we take the positive square root for $\cosh$ is partially that $\cosh\ge0$ and it's probably inherent to the proof you're reading, but it should be noted that $\sinh^{-1}x$ has the explicit formula $\ln\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)$, so you could just compute $\cosh\sinh^{-1}(x)$ directly in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: In $\cosh(\text{arcsinh}(x))$, $\text{arcsinh}(x)$ is the output which is fed into the function $\cosh(x)$. The possible values of this output (the image) is the set of real numbers, which comes from the domain of the inverse function $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$.

Comment: Hence there should be no restrictions on the domain of $\cosh(\text{\arcsinh}(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of $\cosh^{-1}$ may be $[1,\infty)$, but there is no $\cosh^{-1}$ in the identity you're talking about so this interval is irrelevant. The domain of $\sinh^{-1} x$ is all real numbers; its range is all real numbers; the domain of $\cosh$ is all real numbers; so $\cosh(\sinh^{-1}x)$ is well-defined for all $x$.

> Shouldn't there be a restriction on the values that $x$ can take in $\cosh(\sinh^{-1}(x))=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ (such restrictions are present in other items in this problem, for example)?

No.

> In $\cosh^2(\sinh^{-1}(x))=1+x^2$ don't we need to restrict $\sinh^{−1}(x)$ to be in $[1,\infty)$?

No.

> Finally, just to confirm, the reason we take the positive square root is because cosh always positive, correct?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

The formula holds without any restrictions, since $sinh(x)$ is strictly increasing and hence invertible on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $sinh^{-1}(x)=y$. Then $x=sinhy=\dfrac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}$ .

Soving the binomial for $e^{y}$ we get $e^{y}=x\pm \sqrt{x^{2}+1}$. Since $e^{y}$ is positive, the minus case is rejected and we obtain $e^{y}=x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$ and $y=ln(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1})$.

Now $cosh(y)$=$\dfrac{x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}{2}$ +$\dfrac{1}{2(x+\sqrt{x^{2}+1})}$=$\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$.

Thus no restrictions on $x$ are required!!

Comment: There are strictly increasing functions for which you still need to restrict the domain when you take sections, namely $\cosh(\exp^{-1}(x))=\cosh\ln x$ has domain $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: OK ! But this is a complete proof that there is no need for restrictions in this case!

Comment: ... then why leave the false statements there?

Comment: Which are the "false statements"?? Please explain!

Comment: "The formula holds without any restrictions, since sinh(x) is strictly increasing and hence invertible on R."

Comment: My friend, all we need is that it is 1-1. Everything else is superfluous!

Comment: Sweetie, I've told you once and I'll tell you for the last time. 1-1 is not enough: you need bijectivity.

Comment: Whatever you say dear! No point arguing with you! Use Facebook for expressions and conversations like this!